# Passing escaped query string with html special chars between two pages

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, query-string

I'm trying to pass a query string containing special html chars (e.g. `<`). I have to do

```
window.location.href = ".."
```

And on the other page, I have to retrieve this query string using PHP. But when I check it using `isset()` it returns false!

For example, when i need to escape `<p>` using JS like this :

```
function HtmlEncode(s)
      {
          var el = document.createElement("div");
          el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
          s = el.innerHTML;
          return s;
      }

window.location.href = "http://localhost/test.php?t="+HTMLEncode("<p>");
```

Now the url is: `http://localhost/test.php?t=&lt;p&gt;`.

When i do `echo isset($_GET["t"]);`, i get `false` as a result.

Or even when i try `this is a <p> tag`, i get `$_GET["t"]` equals to `this is a`.

Can anyone tell me what's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `HTMLEncode()` use `encodeURIComponent()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` doesn't escape special html chars.

Comment: @RafaelAdel http://jsfiddle.net/BsK8r/ . You can't have `&lt;` or `&gt;` in your URL because `&` is a special character in URLs so you have to URI encode it.

Comment: Hmm, But why my url stays the same wen i use `encodeURIComponent()`, e.g. `&t=<p>` ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel Which browser?

Comment: I'm testing on Chrome, and FF also.